# Is /wp-login.php?redirect_to[] exploitable?

Tags: security

I have a wordpress site, against which I ran a penetration testing tool (debug mode was on at the time)

It reported a (medium severity) issue in that errors were being displayed, and cited

> `/wp-login.php?redirect_to[]=blah`
>
> as triggering a warning: `urlencode()` expects parameter 1 to be string,
>   array given in `/home3/.../wp-includes/general-template.php` on line 340

When I turned debug mode off, and replayed the session the redirect took place, and redirected me to /Array

Which concerns me that wordpress may be trying to evaluate the querystring parameter name in some way that is exploitable.

Am I being overly paranoid?

Comment: I haven't looked into this, but if you'd assume this to be a real security issue I do not think it is a good idea to publicly post and discuss this. Have you seen this? https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/testing/reporting-security-vulnerabilities/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is nothing to worry about.

The redirect target is sanitized and validated a lot. To be honest I think I haven't seen any part of the WordPress code where so many checks happen for the most obscure attack vectors.

Finally when you cast an array to a string `Array` is returned which is what you've seen.

> Arrays are always converted to the string "Array";
>
> [Source](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting)

This happens in [`_deep_replace`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/formatting.php#L3224).

So my personal opinion is this should be fine. Let's see what other people say.

Answer (score 2):

> Which concerns me that wordpress may be trying to evaluate the
>   querystring parameter name in some way that is exploitable.

Why this particular possibility?

[If you look at the source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/general-template.php)-- and the error suggests as much--, what is happening is that WordPress code is attempting to `urlencode` the `redirect_to` query parameter, which it expects to be a string. The square brackets you've added cause that parameter to be an array which, when processed as a string, is "Array".

You might argue that WordPress should check the type of the data before trying to manipulate it, but I don't think there is anything exploitable. Essentially, the array you try to shove into that parameter is converted by PHP to the innocuous string "Array"